# How to iterate over map using mustache in java

Tags: java, mustache

I'm newbie to mustache and was wondering how to iterate over `HashMap` using mustache given this `Map`

```
Map mapA = new HashMap();

mapA.put("key1", "element 1");
mapA.put("key2", "element 2");
mapA.put("key3", "element 3");
```

The map key names vary. Ideally, I want mustache to iterate over both its key and values. So in java it will look like this:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : mapA.entrySet()) {
   String key = entry.getKey();
   String value = entry.getValue();
   // ...
}
```

So can someone tell me how to achieve above in mustache. I mean how would the template looks like? I tried this template but had no luck so far :(

```
{{#mapA}}
  <li>{{key}}</li>
  <li>{{value}}</li>
{{/mapA>
```

So when I run this template, the output `<li>` tags comes out empty, why?
Thanks.

Comment: related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981907/how-to-iterate-over-a-hash-in-mustache-js

Comment: I think that the closest that you can come is to wrap your entry set objects in a `List` and retrieve that

Comment: There's also a syntax error in the template. The last line should be `{{/mapA}}` instead of `{{/mapA>`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know *mustache* but basing on some samples of code I have seen, I think you should define an `entrySet` variable in your Java code like this

```
Set<Map.Entry<String,Object>> entrySet = mapA.entrySet();
```

and use it instead of `mapA` in your *mustache* code

```
{{#entrySet}}
  <li>{{key}}</li>
  <li>{{value}}</li>
{{/entrySet}}
```

Comment: Did this really work ? I tried it and it doesn't work

Comment: At the time I had based my answer on code samples and documentation. The OP accepted the answer, so I assumed it worked for him.

Comment: It did work for me, but I had to configure the MustacheFactory to allow introspection of methods in a java.util.Map. I am using the java version of mustache library from here : https://github.com/spullara/mustache.java

Comment: I see, that's a useful addition to the answer :)

Comment: @Dhiraj could you share how you did that? I don't see how I can configure introspection on the MustacheFactory.

Answer (score 3):

it is much simpler than that, just do it like this:

```
{{#mapA}}
  {{#entrySet}}
    <li>{{key}}</li>
    <li>{{value}}</li>
  {{/entrySet}}
{{/mapA}}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Dici mentioned above, you can use an `entrySet`. You do not have to use any special options on the factory and can pass it directly to `execute`. In your template you can use a top level map if your template is very simple.

**Java**

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("key1", "value1");
map.put("key2", "value2");

Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out);
MustacheFactory mustacheFactory = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
Mustache template = mustacheFactory.compile("map.template");
template.execute(writer, map.entrySet()).close();
```

**Mustache Template (`map.template`)**

```
{{#.}}
keylabel:{{key}} : valuelabel:{{value}}
{{/.}}
```

**Result**

```
keylabel:key1 : valuelabel:value1
keylabel:key2 : valuelabel:value2
```