# Iterating over an object using mustache when you don't know the key name

Tags: javascript, mustache

I'm using mustache with javascript to try and loop through an object to print out the keys and values. The problem is that the names of the keys can be anything, and all the documentation I've seen just shows how to display the key when you know its name. Does anyone know how to do this?

My object looks like:

```js
var obj1 = {
  random1: 10
  random4: 12
  random9: 15
}
```

I've tried doing something like this:

```js
{{#obj1}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}}:{{Value}}</td>
    </tr>
{{/obj1}}
```

But that hasn't worked.

Comment: It looks like there is no easy way of doing that: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9981907/251311

Comment: Yeah i ended up doing a map to place the objects into an array and label the keys how mustache would like. Still a pain to do for something so simple.